# implementing Inheritance in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inheritance

I read about inheritance in standard SQL but I can't implement it in MySQL . Know, how can I use OOP features like inheritance in MySQL ? please give me an example.
thanks

Comment: Where did you read about inheritance in standard SQL? Features of Object-Oriented design (such as inheritance) aren't normally implemented in SQL, which is a language used by Relational Database Management Systems - Relational and OO design are normally regarded as orthogonal too each other.

Comment: http://laughingmeme.org/2004/08/14/mysql-and-the-case-for-class-table-inheritance/

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases (such as MySQL) rarely have much, if any, support for OO-concepts such as inheritance.

I suggest looking into [Object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) - as mentioned in the comments, there are [significant difficulties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) in persisting Objects in Relational databases, so there is a [wide variety of software tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) available to assist with this process.